# How can I calculate $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac {(\sin(x)-\tan(x))^2}{(e^x-1-\ln(x+1))^3}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> How can I calculate $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac {(\sin(x)-\tan(x))^2}{(e^x-1-\ln(x+1))^3}$?

I have tried really hard to solve this limit, but I cannot solve it. The answer is $1/4$, but I want to learn how to do it, because learning is my goal. Thanks for your time

Comment: Limited expansions of sine and tangent around 0 at order 3, of the exponential around 0 at order 2 and of the logarithm around 1 at order 2, makes this computation entirely direct: $$\sin x=x-\tfrac16x^3+o(x^3)\qquad\tan x=x+\tfrac13x^3+o(x^3)$$ and $$e^x=1+x+\tfrac12x^2+o(x^2)\qquad\log(1+x)=x-\tfrac12x^2+o(x^2)$$ hence the limit is $$\frac{(-\tfrac16-\tfrac13)^2}{(\tfrac12-(-\tfrac12))^3}=\frac14$$

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to handle a limit of this form is using Taylor series.

We know that in a neighborhood of $x=0$:

- $\sin x=x-\frac16x^3+O(x^5)$
- $\tan x=x+\frac13x^3+O(x^5)$
- $e^x=1+x+\frac12x^2+O(x^3)$
- $\ln(x+1)=x-\frac12x^2+O(x^3)$

So $\sin x-\tan x=-\frac12x^3+O(x^4)$ and $(\sin x-\tan x)^2=\frac1{4}x^6+O(x^7)$.  Likewise, $e^x-1-\ln(x+1)=x^2+O(x^3)$ and $(e^x-1-\ln(x+1))^3=x^6+O(x^7)$, so the limit in question is $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\frac14x^6+O(x^7)}{x^6+O(x^7)}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac14+O(x)\right)=\frac14$.

Comment: Thanks to all the replies, but what does it mean $O(x^3)$

Comment: @OscarLaraCrosas $O(f(x))$ is shorthand for 'terms that are no larger than $f(x)$ in whatever limit is being taken'; this can be formalized, but the informal definition is a lot easier to understand. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation for more details.

Comment: $O(x^n)$ denotes some function that goes to zero at least as fast as $x^n$ as $x \to 0$. That is, a function $f$ is said to be $O(x^n)$ as $x\to 0$ if there is a constant $C > 0$ and an $\epsilon > 0$ so that for $-\epsilon < x < \epsilon$, we have $\lvert f(x) \rvert \le C\lvert x \rvert^n$.

Comment: That's a much better statement, yes. My 'no larger than' was more than a little sloppy; I meant 'no larger than' asymptotically, and absolutely meant 'a multiple of'. Mea culpa.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I think the last line should be $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac14+O(x)$ but I'm not sure. If I'm wrong could you explain why it's $O(\frac1x)$?

Comment: @John11 No, you're right - technically it _is_ $O(\frac1x)$ as $x\to0$, but that's not terribly useful since that just says it's one fourth plus a potentially unbounded quantity!  $O(x)$ is what I meant, and is actually relevant to the problem.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Take the parts separately, evaluate

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x-\tan x}{x^3}$$

this can be rewritten as

$$\frac{\sin x-\tan x}{x^3}=\frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{1}{\cos x}\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}$$

Then find
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1-\ln(x+1)}{x^2}$$

this can also be expressed in terms of standard limits

$$\frac{e^x-1-\ln(x+1)}{x^2}=\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}+\frac{x-\ln(x+1)}{x^2}\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1$$

Put it all together you get $\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it without Taylor series.

Start by noting that

$$(\sin x-\tan x)^2={\sin^2x(1-\cos x)^2\over\cos^2x}={\sin^2x(1-\cos x)^2(1+\cos x)^2\over\cos^2(1+\cos x)^2}={\sin^6x\over\cos^2x(1+\cos x)^2}$$

and that $\cos^2x(1+\cos x)^2\to4$ as $x\to0$, so that

$$\lim_{x\to0}{(\sin x-\tan x)^2\over(e^x-1-\ln(x+1))^3}={1\over4}\lim_{x\to0}\left(\sin^2x\over e^x-1-\ln(x+1) \right)^3$$

Thus it suffices to show that

$$\lim_{x\to0}{\sin^2x\over e^x-1-\ln(x+1)}=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\sin x\over x \right)^2\lim_{x\to0}{x^2\over e^x-1-\ln(x+1)}=1$$

The limit for $\sin x\over x$ should be familiar.  The other limit is easily done with two rounds of L'Hopital:

$$\lim_{x\to0}{x^2\over e^x-1-\ln(x+1)}=\lim_{x\to0}{2x\over e^x-{1\over x+1}}=\lim_{x\to0}{2\over e^x+{1\over(x+1)^2}}={2\over1+1}=1$$